# Unresolved external symbols in object file(help.obj)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker, vlc, unresolved-external

I'm compiling VLC 2.1.0 Source code in VS 2010 but getting some unresolved external symbols in help.obj file. The errors are as follows.

> Error 54  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual
>   struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall
>   UpdateDialog::metaObject(void)const "
>   (?metaObject@UpdateDialog@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ) D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\lib_plugin\help.obj
>
> Error 55  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual
>   void * __thiscall UpdateDialog::qt_metacast(char const *)"
>   (?qt_metacast@UpdateDialog@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)  D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\lib_plugin\help.obj
>
> Error 56  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual
>   int __thiscall UpdateDialog::qt_metacall(enum
>   QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)"
>   (?qt_metacall@UpdateDialog@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z) D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\lib_plugin\help.obj
>
> Error 57  error LNK1120: 3 unresolved
>   externals D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\Release\plugins\lib_plugin.dll

I tried, Generating Meta Object file(help.moc.cpp) but it didn't help me.
Any suggestions would be appreciated. I'm new to this Win32 environment.

Comment: Even i too facing the same issue can anybody please help me out?

Comment: @adarshaU Have you used mingW tool chain to build VLC?

Comment: yes i am using mingW tool..